# How to speed up R loop operations over 3 Dimensional Array of variable size?

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an R script that I wrote which simulates how long particles need to equilibrate in a room. The room is represented with a 3 dimensional array of size max_size. Currently the script works as it is intended, but the real run time of the script is so slow that it is nearly unusable. I have tried adjusting my algorithm to reduce the number of times that the array needs to be looped over, but it is still many magnitudes slower than when I wrote this code in FORTRAN previously. How can I adjust this script in order to reduce the runtime?

Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
options(warn=1)
max_size <- 10
use_partition = 1

cube <- array(dim=c(max_size, max_size, max_size))  
cube[,,]=0.0

diffusion_coefficient <- 0.175
room_dimension <- 5
mol_speed <- 250 # speed of molecules based on 100 g/mol at RT
timestep <- (room_dimension/mol_speed)/max_size # h in seconds
dist_between <- room_dimension/max_size
DTerm <- diffusion_coefficient*timestep/(dist_between*dist_between)
cube[1,1,1] <- 1.0e21 # initial mass of particles
time <- 0 # keep up with accumulated system time
ratio <- 0
part_height <- floor(max_size*0.75)
center <- floor(max_size/2)

# the partition is defined as:
#   1 space (index) "wide" on the X axis
#   spans 75% (rounded) of the "height" (Y axis)
#   spans 100% of the "depth" (z axis)
# partition spaces are indicated with the value -69.0
# partition spaces cannot be diffused from nor into
if(use_partition == 1) {
    for (j in 1:part_height) {
        cube[center,j,] <- -69.0 # flag partition spaces with -69.0
    }
}

repeat { #R replacement for Do While
    for (i in 1:nrow(cube)) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(cube)) {
            for (k in 1:max_size) {
                if(cube[i,j,k] != -69.0) {
                    for (off in seq(from=-1, to=1, by=2)) {
                        if (i+off >= 1 && i+off <= max_size) {
                            change <- (cube[i,j,k] - cube[i+off,j,k])*DTerm
                            cube[i,j,k] = cube[i,j,k] - change
                            cube[i+off,j,k] = cube[i+off,j,k] + change
                        }
                        if (j+off >= 1 && j+off <= max_size) {
                            change <- (cube[i,j,k] - cube[i,j+off,k])*DTerm
                            cube[i,j,k] = cube[i,j,k] - change
                            cube[i,j+off,k] = cube[i,j+off,k] + change
                        }
                        if (k+off >= 1 && k+off <= max_size) {
                            change <- (cube[i,j,k] - cube[i,j,k+off])*DTerm
                            cube[i,j,k] = cube[i,j,k] - change
                            cube[i,j,k+off] = cube[i,j,k+off] + change
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    time = time+timestep

    #check mass for consistency
    sumval <- 0.0
    maxval <- cube[1,1,1]
    minval <- cube[1,1,1]
    for(i in 1:nrow(cube)) {
        for(j in 1:ncol(cube)) {
            for(k in 1:max_size) {
                if(cube[i,j,k] != -69.0) {
                    if(cube[i,j,k] > maxval) {
                        maxval = cube[i,j,k]
                    }
                if(cube[i,j,k] < minval) {
                    minval = cube[i,j,k]
                }
                    sumval = sumval + cube[i,j,k]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ratio <- minval / maxval
    cat(time, " ", ratio, " ", sumval, "\n")
    if(ratio >= 0.99) {
        break  
    }
}
cat("Box equilibrated in ", time,  " seconds of simulated time.\n")
```

Comment: You could convert to [tag:Rcpp] - I don't think there's be a lot of change in code. http://markovjumps.blogspot.com/2011/12/r-array-to-rcpparmadillo-cube.html?m=1

Comment: Generally running `if(){}`, especially with nesting of `if` conditionals inside loops is a prescription for slowness. You should make an effort to vectorize your algorithm. Since the algorithm is not described, there may not be much interest in offering advice.

Comment: For what it's worth, the second big loop is largely ```maxval <- max(cube); minval <- min(cube); sumval <- sum(cube);``` you would also need to address your logic regarding ```-69```